# DirectoryNotFoundException: "Could not find part of the path", but the path exists (Directory.Exists returns true)

Tags: c#, .net, directory

There is a shared network folder at `\\FILESERVER\MyFolder`. The security principal `Everyone` has `Full Control` on `This folder, subfolders and files`. There are no `DENY` permissions on the folder. There are three users, and all of them can use File Explorer to enter the directory and create a file named `test.txt`.

This code runs fine for two of the users:

```
string testLocation = @"\\FILESERVER\MyFolder\";
string testFullPath = Path.Combine(testLocation, "test.txt");
Directory.CreateDirectory(testLocation);
bool exists = Directory.Exists(testLocation); // RETURNS TRUE!
File.Create(testFullPath); // For one user, this raises:
// System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find part of the path
// '\\FILESERVER\MyFolder\test.txt'
```

So `Directory.CreateDirectory` runs fine (the folder already exists), but `File.Create` seems to think the directory does not exist. As that user, I can type in `\\FILESERVER\MyFolder` in Explorer, see the existing files there and create new files, no problem. But not when running the code above.

The program's process is running under the user in question.

**This only happens with network paths, not local paths.** If I change `\\FILESERVER\MyFolder` to `C:\Users\Username\Desktop`, the file is created.

The background for the problem is that the program fails to export an XLSX file to the network folder for this specific user. In this case, I attempted to work around the problem after days of researching and not finding anything: If the file fails to export to the network folder, the program exports it to Desktop and then attempts to move it to the network folder. Of course, the program fails when moving. I narrowed it down to the snippet shown above. The code shown above is identical to the code that fails, except that I've changed the name of the server and folder for the example.

Any ideas?

Comment: I' thinking two things 1) The user account on local and remote machines have to be linked.  On a corporate network Group Policies are used.  So the policy may not be setup on the remote machine. 2) VS doesn't run as Admin.  To run VS as Admin right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng But Everyone has Full Control on the folder, subfolders and files (all explicit permissions replaced), and the user is signed in as DOMAINNAME\Username. DOMAINNAME\Username is also explicitly given permission. I am starting to suspect that this is a Windows bug and not a bug in the code.

Comment: If you are correct then use explorer and see if the files can be opened.  You can open a cmd.exe and the use >notepad path\filename.  You should see if you can edit outside c# before using c#.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Renaming the directory worked. Instead of `\\FILESERVER\MyFolder`, the folder is now named `\\FILESERVER\MyFolderNew`, and it's working. If I rename the folder back to `MyFolder`, it stops working again.

I don't have time to dig deeper. There are no firewall/antivirus rules regarding this directory, that's all I know. Renaming the folder works for us.